# How can I get the ascii decimal values of characters in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, ascii, decimal

```
user=> (char 65)
\A
user=> (char 97)
\a
user=> (str (char 65))
"A"
user=> (str (char 97))
"a"
```

These are the characters from the ascii decimal values ...
How do I get the ascii decimal values from the characters?

Comment: Note, that Java and Clojure are using Unicode (UTF-16), not ASCII. You can get things like `(char 0x439) => \й` and `(int \й) => 1081`.

Answer (score 15):

A character is a number, it's just that clojure is showing it to you as a char.  The easiest way is to just cast that char to an int.

e.g.

```
user=> (int \A)
65
user=> (int (.charAt "A" 0))
65
```

Comment: I was going to add that you can do math directly on the character, but it looks like you can't in Clojure. Its represented as a java.lang.Character (rather than a char), and Character does not extend java.lang.Number, so the math operators do not work out of the box on characters in Clojure.

Comment: just like with characters primitives in Java - I don't think you can add those either.

Comment: Being a newbie in Clojure I have not adapted my mind yet to so many possibilities. Thank you to put me on my way.

Comment: Notice that you can't use this in ClojureScript. In that case you need `(.charCodeAt \A 0)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775349/ordinal-int-ascii-value-of-character

Answer (score 12):

```
user=> (doseq [c "aA"] (printf "%d%n" (int c)))
97
65
nil
user=> (map int "aA");;
(97 65)
user=> (apply str (map char [97 65]))
"aA"
```

Comment: Beautiful way to convert a string to its decimal values!!