# Ordinal/int/ascii value of character

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In the clojure repl I can do:

```
=> (int \a)
97
```

In closurescript, I keep getting

```
=> (int \a)
0
```

In my current clojurescript project I've defined a var:

```
(def ord-a (int \a))
```

When I inspect the emitted javascript I see:

```
ord_a = ("a" | (0));
```

Which explains the discrepancy, but doesn't really do what I want. So:

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. How do I get the ordinal/int/ascii value of a character in clojurescript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clojurescript does not have [character literals](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#the-reader).

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94037/convert-character-to-ascii-code-in-javascript) you can get it using js interop:

```
=> (.charCodeAt \a 0)
97
```